# Hamiltonian & Eulerian paths, one vertex graph

Tags: graph-theory

Does the graph with only one vertex have an Eulerian path? And, does it have a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: I don't know if everyone defines it the same way, but Diestel's book, at least, allows a path to consist of a single vertex, which means that the answer is yes.

Comment: @Andrew: You could post that as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if all graph theory books treat degenerate cases the same way, but Diestel's *Graph Theory*, at least, allows a path to have length $0$, i.e., to consist of a single vertex with no edges.  If a graph consists of a single vertex $v$, then the path consisting of $v$ is vacuously Eulerian.  It is also a Hamiltonian path, since it contains all of the vertices of the graph.